# Sketchflow component target parent state

Tags: expression-blend, sketchflow

I'm using Sketchflow in Expression Blend 4 RC (although this is relevant to Blend 3 too).

I have a screen with a datagrid on it (MainScreen) and there's a "New" button.

I have a component screen that has a generic form (GenericForm) and a "Save and close" button.

I have two states on MainScreen:

State1 (and default): GenericForm visibility set to Hidden

State2: GenericForm visibility set to Visible

The "New" button on MainScreen has: Active State = State2, meaning when the "New" button is pressed, it changes the state of MainScreen to State2 (where the GenericForm component is visible).

My problem is that I cannot link the "Save and close" button on GenericForm to State1 on MainScreen. In effect I would like to be able to press "Save and close" and for the MainScreen to set its state to State1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WPF or Silverlight? In WPF you can use routed events to bubble up an event like that into the parent control, I posted a simple example here:
http://chuckhays.net/2010/05/21/very-simple-routed-event-example/

If you are using Silverlight, I can try to come up with another example that will help you.